# Pub install fail, Package "html5lib" doesn't have a pubspec.yaml file

Tags: dart, html5lib, dart-pub

I've created a simple project. This is my pubspec.yaml

```
name:  testapp
description:  test application
dependencies: 
  html5lib: 0.0.12
```

And now i get this error

```
Pub install fail, Resolving dependencies...
Package "html5lib" doesn't have a pubspec.yaml file.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are on windows?  Dart seems to setup shortcuts (hard dir links?) between the packages folder in a project and where the packages are stored.  So if you delete your packages dir from within Eclipse, it will trash the folder that stores the actual package.

On Windows 7, the folder is:

> C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\Pub\

Go ahead and delete its contents and run `pub install` again.

If you start getting errors about UnitTest or other core libraries, you may need to re-download the Dark-SDK (or dart editor) and replace it.

Comment: They are soft links (junction points) not hard links, but otherwise, you're exactly right here. This sounds like an Eclipse issue. It really shouldn't be traversing into a junction point and deleting its contents. :(